# How can I get a macro to automatically trigger when a cell reaches a certain value in a Google Sheet?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-macros

What I need is for a macro I've recorded called SwitchHotSeat to trigger when the value of cell F3 goes above £1,000,000.00 0r 1000000 or the LEN of cell F3 goes over that length.

I can find guides for doing this in Excel, but not for Google Sheets. below is just the code for my macro.

```
function SwitchHotSeat() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
      spreadsheet.getRange('3:3').activate();

 spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().deleteRows(spreadsheet.getActiveRange().getRow(), spreadsheet.getActiveRange().getNumRows());
  spreadsheet.getActiveRangeList().setBackground('#ff0000')
  .setFontColor('#ffffff');
};
```

The macro works fine. I just need a way of triggering it when that cell goes over the 1000000.

Answer (score 0):

You could use simple or installable triggers. See

- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers
- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable

Example of using onEdit simple trigger

```
function onEdit(e){
  if(/* add here your conditions */) {
     SwitchHotSeat();
  }
}
```

NOTE: on edit and on change triggers are triggered only when an user edit the spreadsheet.

Comment: Thanks @Rubén, my conditions are If cell F3 >=1000000 how would I put that in the brackets there?
 
I tried it as (!F3 >=1000000) but got a 

"ReferenceError: "F3" is not defined. (line 2, file "Code")Dismiss" message.

Comment: Also, I realise it would only trigger when a user edits the sheet, but if they update the value in the cell from the attached google form, would that count as editing it?

Comment: @Simȱn  You have to learn a bit of JavaScript and how Google Apps Script gets data from a spreadsheet. If you didn't this already, please read https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets

Comment: @Simȱn onEdit/onChange will not work for updates made by an attached form. Instead use a onFormSubmit trigger.

Comment: Thanks again @Rubén, yes, I will study how to script more, I have started a free course. :)

Comment: Hi @Rubén, can you have a look at the code in my own answer above please, this very nearly works now, it triggers the switchHotSeat macro, when the form is submitted, however it does it no matter what value is in cell F3. Any idea what I have wrong?

Comment: @Simȱn Please read https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/conditionals

Comment: Thanks @Rubén but as you can see from my answer I have found a solution and don't really have a need to learn JavaScript fully now.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case it helps anyone else with a similar issue, I discovered (by logging) that it was returning an object, rather than a number before, so the following code worked fine in the end.

```
function onFormSubmit(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
   var millionaire24 = ss.getSheetByName('Millionaire24.');
    var cellValue = millionaire24.getRange(3,6,1,1).getValues();
  Number(cellValue)
if(cellValue[0] >= 1000000)switchHotSeat();


}
```

Comment: `Number(cellValue)` isn't required. Instead of `getValues()` and `cellValue[0] >= 1000000` you could use getValue() and `cellValue >= 1000000` respectively

Comment: Ya, I did do that first but had to use the Number as otherwise logger was showing the cellVallue as an object, rather than a number.